# cocos2d mac application how to add splash screen when launching (Default.png)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, macos, cocos2d-iphone

i am migrating my iOS app onto mac. the loading time is a bit long (around 5 seconds) thus i need a splash loading screen (Just like Default.png image for iOS) but the project made from cocos2d template just shows a white screen. not sure about other apps. so is there anyway to set it?

I know that the screen size is not fixed on a mac app. but i have set a default size. and use auto scale in case of full screen mode.

EDIT:

I have tried a light weight loading scene as well but failed since the MainScene itself is light weight as well. I think the major loading time is due to the cocos2d environment set up.

Comment: I don't know a valid answer to give you but I just want to say I'm a big fan! And I played your game for years on the website way before it was on iOS 0:)

Answer (score 2):

In OS X a window appears when the application launches, it's not designed to use splash screens.You might want to reconsider that choice.

But if the window is still to slow to load or to display its contents, you can still do that but manually, it isn't easy like in iOS.You need to display another view inside the window until it loads.

**EDIT**

A little more of context: for example you can set in your xib file an image view containing the image do display.
Then you make start another thread that loads all the content that you need.After this, run a selector on the main thread that updates the window.

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited the answer.Unfortunately there isn't a so easy solution for Mac OS X.

Comment: how? could u have a look at the cocos project? the default xib is just a simple view with nothing. i tried to add a label on that but it didn't show up

Comment: You need to load it, for example with a window controller.The important thing is that you load it before initializing cocos2 stuff.

Comment: the cocos2d project is kind of complicated. can you try a new project?

Answer (score 2):

Based on my tests in Cocos2d 1.0.1 & 2.0 the basic Cocos2d OS X app launches really quickly.

This makes it seem pretty likely that it's something about your first scene that is taking a long time to load, or something else.  Instruments can help you gather information about what your app is doing.

I suggest you make an initial lightweight cocos2d scene that will load quickly at startup and then load your second scene and transition to it.  Ideally the loading of the assets for your second scene would be asynchronous (at least the ones that are slow). There are numerous blog posts on how to do this. (search for "cocos2d asynchronous loading" and you'll find many, such as this one:  [How to preload your game assets in a loading scene](http://xperienced.com.pl/blog/how-to-preload-your-game-assets-in-loading-scene), though something more recent might be preferable).

Comment: No, not at all. It still shows the blank page for a long time and then just a flash of loading scene, then switches to main scene (my MainScene is pretty much just simple menus). I believe the launching delay is due to open gl init stuff, which is before any scenes.

Comment: Cocos2d 1.0.1 sample OS X app launches and shows the simple scene *very* fast.  Try creating a test project from the sample template for OS X for the version of cocos2d you are using and see if you see the same thing.  Likely it's the synchronous loading of assets for your first scene (won't show scene until they are loaded). That's why you make a really simple loading scene that'll load and display fast and then switch to your big scene.

Comment: I have just updated to Cocos2d 2.0 release and built the simple template (no box2d or anything) and it also launches *very* quickly.

Comment: updated my answer to reflect having done tests with 2.0 as well as 1.0.1.  If you tell us which version of cocos2d you are using that might help.